# Java ProcessBuilder to run a java with ThreadPoolExecutor does not work properly on ubuntu

Tags: java, multithreading, ubuntu, processbuilder

After running the app for somedays, I found out that some JVM crash report are created in the /root folder
The log file starts with this info

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f050013cdeb, pid=31295, tid=139659437045504
#
# JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64     compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x86deb]  unsigned long+0x15b
#
```

I found out that the below behavior happens only on Ubuntu

> java version "1.6.0_26"
>       Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
>       Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
>       Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-36-server #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 8 22:44:38 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

But the same jars run on Windows 7 professional 32 bit **works correctly**

> java version "1.6.0_22"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)

I have a multithreaded java app (APP1) using a ThreadPoolExecutor to process some objects.
When I run it on Linux from the command line it works as expected. Then I written another java app (APP2) that uses `ProcessBuilder.start` to execute the multithreaded app.

When I use APP2 to run APP1, I found out that the behavior of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in APP1 is different where some threads are reused with their old data more than once.
my code is something like this:
App1:

```
    myProcessor processor = new myProcessor(data);
    threadExecuter.execute(processor);
```

`myProcessor` is implementing runnable, and data is stored there in a private variable.

This the code of `myProcessor` class

```
    private class myProcessor implements Runnable {
    public myProcessor(Data data)
    {
    myData=data;
    }

    private Data myData;

DataDAO datadao=new DataDAO();

    public void run() {
        Boolean processed = false;
        if (myData != null) {
            if(Logger.isDebug())
            {
                Logger.logInfo("-- thread:"+ Thread.currentThread().getName()+" processing "+myData.getId());
            }
            processed = dataHandler.process(myData.getMade(), myData.getText(), myData.getSc().getComp(), myData.getSc(), myData.getOp(),myData.getId());
            myData.setProcessed(processed);
            myData.setStatus(1);
            try {
                if(myData.isProcessed()) datadao.UpdateProcessedStatus(myData);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.logError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

When I check the log file, I find that Thread name is run twice with the same data id, where it never happen when I run App1 normally from the command line.

Did anyone encountered such behavior before?

Comment: Can you more detail to the statement "some threads are reused with their old data more than once".  What data?  Can you show some examples?  Maybe some code from `myProcessor` would be good too.

Comment: updated with some code from APP1

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code.  I suspect that something is submitting the job to the `threadExecuter` twice.  I'd put a breakpoint in your `run()` method and debug your application to see who's calling it twice.

Comment: thank you @Gray for your help, but how do I debug it when I am running it from APP2 ? note the problem is visible when the above code is executed using `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: You have to launch it suspended, using a different debugger listening port if you're also debugging the launcher.  It will wait until the debugger connects before proceeding.  For example `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044` to cause the second JVM to pause on startup to wait for a connection on port 1044 from the debugger.

Comment: Do you have any other JVMs installed on your linux box?  Is it possible that APP2 is executing APP1 using a different JVM?

Comment: @Jakrabbit I don't think so, I've upgraded to the latest JVM and didn't see the problem again!